# Redshift - Weird behaviour from TO_TIMESTAMP function

Tags: date, timestamp, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to create a timestamp from separated date and time fields. The date field is of 'date' type while the time field is 'varchar'. The table has just over 60k records. Date is in YYYY-MM-DD format, ie 2017-07-25. Time is in HH:MIpm format, ie 4:25pm.

I run the following query to try and create the timestamp:

```
select *, 
       to_timestamp(TO_CHAR("date", 'YYYY-MM-DD')||' '||(case when "time"='' then '11:59pm' else "time" end), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MIpm') as REQUIRED_TIMESTAMP 
from TABLE;
```

However, it only returns 1023 records. Here's what makes things even weirder:

i. The records that are returned aren't always the same on subsequent runs. However, there is always 1023 records returned. On one run the first few IDs would be 43, 55, 63, 69, etc. and on the next run it'd be different. Sometimes I'd get the following error:

`Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  invalid value for "HH" in source string`

ii. I used `CAST(as timestamp)` instead, it'd show the timestamp in a different format but again it'd only show 1023 records.

iii. It's not a specific time value that is omitted. A record with time 7:30pm may be omitted, but another record with 7:30pm shows up just fine.

Is there something wrong with my query? Could it be a problem with the data or is this an issue with Redshift?

Comment: It almost sounds like you're using a SQL client that has a default setting to limit results to the first 1023 records. Does (ii) still occur if you add an explicit ORDER BY clause?

Comment: I agree, this sounds like an SQL client doing strange stuff. The value of 1023 is very close to 1024, which sounds like some default value. I'd suggest you start by getting a consistent result coming back, then try to work on fixing your CAST. Which SQL client are you using? Have you tried running the same command in the Redshift console in the SQL window)?

Comment: So I ran the query on Redshift query editor, and it also gave only 1023 records. I don't think my SQL client is limiting results to first 1023 records because when I run the same query minus the ```to_timestamp``` function it returns all records, ie:

```select *, TO_CHAR("date", 'YYYY-MM-DD')||' '||(case when "time"='' then '11:59pm' else "time" end) as REQUIRED_TIMESTAMP from TABLE;```

In any case, the SQL client is Table Plus and I've found it problem free for the most part.

Also when using ```order by id``` it doesn't seem to omit any records but it is still only returning 1023.

Comment: Can you check distinct "time" and see they are in the right format, all of them? 'invalid value for "HH" in source string' makes me suspect something is weird there.

Comment: Thanks @MiloBellano, that was indeed what the problem was, some values were anomalous.